# ListView without extending ListActivity

Tags: java, android, listview, import

I have an application that extends ActionBarActivity, but I'm using ListView and I need to implement OnItemClickListener and I'm not sure how to do this without extending ListActivity. Also I want to ask you: Moreover I have a button and I need to listen if the button is clicked or if an item in the list is clicked. I'm not pretty sure how to do this. 
So I would really appreciate if you help me :)

Here is my code:

```
package com.src.vicnote;

import java.io.File;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

        Button newButton;

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/VICNote";
        String lastOfPath;
        File f = new File(path);
    File files[] = f.listFiles();
    String[] theNamesOfFiles = new String[files.length + 1];


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        theNamesOfFiles[0] = "Create new note";

        for(int i = 1; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {

                lastOfPath = files[i-1].toString().split("/")[files[i-1].toString().split("/").length-1];
                theNamesOfFiles[i] = lastOfPath.replace(".txt","");
                Log.d("Files", "String: " + theNamesOfFiles[i]);
        }

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notesList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                                                                                                                theNamesOfFiles);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        newButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNew);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                Intent newNote = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewNoteActivity.class);
                                startActivity(newNote);
                        }
                });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: you can have a `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()..` and implement `onItemCLick`. But `newButton` belong to the listview row??

Comment: Thank you for y our reply. There is a button over the listview.

Comment: the buttons belongs to the rows?

Comment: No it doesn't. The button is above the list and is not connected with the list.

Comment: igonore my previous comments as you do not have a custom adapter with button in each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the `OnItemClickListener` interface and override `onItemClick`

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
{

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.this, "List View row Clicked at"+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

If the button belongs to `activity_main.xml` then what you have

```
newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

is right

Comment: So you are telling me that the button listener is parallel with the listview listener?

Comment: @user3132352 button listener is separate from listview listener

Comment: Yes it is separate but if (for example) first is the button listener and then is the listview listener are both of them gonna work?

Comment: @user3132352 to get names use `theNamesOfFiles[position]` in `onItemClick`. `position` gives you the index of list item. `view` is the View for the row infalted

Answer (score 1):

You can set item click listener for `ListView` using this code.

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
            long arg3) 
      { 
        // it is used to get the clicked string             
      String theNamesOfFile = adapter.getItem(position);
      }
   });
```

I guess it can help you.

Comment: Thank you, I want to ask you something if it's not a problem.
I can't really understand how onItemClick method works. I'm confused with the arguments and also every item in my list has a name. How I can find out which item is clicked and get it's name?

Comment: I have update the code. You can use this code to get the value of clicked item. I thing it can help you.